# Creating Visual on Line and Clustered Column Chart

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have line and clustered column chart (shown on "Graph" image) and I want to add a visual like drawn on "Graph" image
Clustered Columns : Planned Labor Data and Actual Labor Data
Lines : Cumulative Planned Labor data and Cumulative Labor Data

I keep data for both planned (P_Planned_Labor) and actual (Z_Labor) in 2 column table (date and data). Also I have a Date table (Z_Tarih) and it has only dates which has relation with planned and actual tables.

Dax Measures:

- [Toplam Bugdeted] = Sum of Planned Bugdet

Columns;

- Labor_Earned % İlerleme = DIVIDE(sum(Z_Labor[Değer]),[Toplam Budgeted],0)  "percentage of actual labor of this week)
- Labor_Plan % İlerleme = DIVIDE(SUM(P_Planned_Labor[Değer]),[Toplam Budgeted],0) "percentage of planned labor of this week)

Lines;

- Labor_Earned Küm. % İlerleme = DIVIDE(CALCULATE(SUM(Z_Labor[Değer]),FILTER(ALL(Z_Tarih),Z_Tarih[Tarih]<=MAX(Z_Labor[Tarih]))),[Toplam Budgeted],0) "percentage of all actual from begining"
- Labor_Plan Küm. % İlerleme = DIVIDE(CALCULATE(SUM(P_Planned_Labor[Değer]),FILTER(ALL(Z_Tarih),Z_Tarih[Tarih]<=MAX(Z_Tarih[Tarih]))),[Toplam Budgeted],0) "percentage of all planned from begining"

the chart i used doesnt allow (or i couldn't figure it out) to add visual which show difference value among lines.

Is there any chart that allow me to do that ?
or what measure should i add ?

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8pjR.png)
[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMNyU.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you simply can't achieve a chart like that (in which you plot the difference in that way), you will have to find a different way to show it.

for the difference itself, just create a measure like `AB difference = [Measure A] - [Measure B]`, let's call it "difference"

**Idea 1**

- you can then show the "difference" in the tooltip section, it will be visible only on hover (and you can put there as many differences as you want, one for "earned" and one for "planned"

**Idea 2**

Use the "Line and Stacked Column Chart", split the current chart in 2

- In the "column values" put "labor" and "difference"
- in the "line values" put the total value

This will allow seeing the current value and the difference like you asked BUT you won't be able to have multiple "categories" of measure in the same chart, as all the values will be stacked. therefore you will need to have one chart for "labor earned" and one for "labor planned".

You might want to put the 2 chart side by side (or one below the other) and maybe with a somehow fixed scale in order to make the comparison between the two easier

Comment: thanks for respond. those may work. i was wondering, especially if i can add that visual and the answer is "no". idea-2 worth to try